# Does Angular support Recursive Nested Dynamic Components?

Tags: angular

This is the sole guide I can find.

**https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader**

I am using the same method so everything is quite basic. Until you have a recursive component.

Let's imagine this shape of data:

```
{
   component: {
       id: "container",
       components: [
           {
              id: "container",
              components: [
                  {
                       id: "text",
                       data: "Hi"
                  }
              ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

What this means is that:

1. `Container` requires access to `DynamicComponentLoader`
2. `DynamicComponentLoader` can construct a `Container`
3. See the first step.

Angular warns me that there is a Circular Dependency and quite rightly so.

But I have spent a week on this issue and I definitely cannot see a solution.  I think I am going to have to stop using dynamic components, and am forced to return to using `@Input`.  Like `ButtonContainer` and `ImageContainer` and so on. I can't seem to make a generic container.  I am stuck on a flat surface.

That is a real pain.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about ComponentFactoryResolver ? Could you provide a sample ?

Comment: I created a working sample without any problems base on https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsivwn

Comment: @JEY I am sorry I took so long, I was mulling over your amazing sample! Thanks for taking the time to do that!! I ditched my "Service based" component creation and moved it into a `ContainerComponent` just like your sample.  Now there is no circular reference and I am a happy man. Do you want to move this comment into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks again!

Comment: I add the answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post my comment as an answer as requested by @OP.

There is a great example in the [official angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader) on how to create dynamic component. Basically it contains a component (`AdBannerComponent`) that can create component from a given list using [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver).

Based on this example we can create a new component that just reuse the `AdBannerComponent`:

```
import { Component, Input, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdComponent } from './ad.component';
import { AdItem } from './ad-item';
import { AdDirective } from './ad.directive';
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="job-ad">
    <app-ad-banner [ads]="ads"></app-ad-banner>
    </div>
`})
export class HeroSubProfileComponent implements AdComponent, OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  ads: AdItem[];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ads = this.data;
  }
}
```

This component will create dynamically the component given as an input in `data`. We can also directly reuse `AdBannerComponent` as is by updating it's definition to match `AdItem`:

```
export class AdBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ads: AdItem[];
  currentAdIndex = -1;
  @ViewChild(AdDirective) adHost: AdDirective;
  interval: any;
  @Input() data: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.data != null) {
      this.ads = this.data;
    }
    this.loadComponent();
    this.getAds();
  }
```

If we update the `AdService` (providing the list of component to create) with the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdService {
  getAds() {
    return [
      new AdItem(HeroProfileComponent, {name: 'Bombasto', bio: 'Brave as they come'}),

      new AdItem(HeroProfileComponent, {name: 'Dr IQ', bio: 'Smart as they come'}),

      new AdItem(HeroJobAdComponent,   {headline: 'Hiring for several positions',
                                        body: 'Submit your resume today!'}),

      new AdItem(HeroJobAdComponent,   {headline: 'Openings in all departments',
                                        body: 'Apply today'}),
      // component using composition
      new AdItem(HeroSubProfileComponent, [new AdItem(HeroProfileComponent, {name: 'Great Scott', bio: 'Awesome'})]),
      // directly using AdBannerComponent
      new AdItem(AdBannerComponent, [new AdItem(HeroProfileComponent, {name: 'Bombasto', bio: 'Brave as they come'})])
    ];
  }
}
```

We are creating dynamic component inside another one and we can do it as deep as we want.

You can find a running example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsivwn.