# Dynamic Components and Lazy Loading, can Angular Elements help me?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I am using Dynamic Components and I am re-writing this to try to better explain.

**AppModule**

My App Module contains an `entryComponents` array which contains these 2 things

- `ContainerComponent`
- `TextComponent`

Now I can go crazy until my heart is content

[image]

**GameModule**

However, now I have a problem. Some of my Components are Games and they are heavy and indeed they may never be used.  Therefore, I have to have Lazy Loaded routes. `GameModule` has the following

- `GameContainer`
- `GameComponent`

So now I am in this place:

[image]

And what I am actually aiming for is this:

[image]

My problem is with that `GameContainer`. Originally it was a `DynamicComponentService` but I couldn't use this because of circular dependencies with nested containers.  [See my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422961/does-angular-support-recursive-nested-dynamic-components) where I moved this out of a service and back into `Container`.

The problem is that I can't seem to successfully extend `Container`. I was hoping I could do this:

```
protected constructComponent(config: IThing){  
       switch (config.selector){
           default: 
              // `app-text` will be handled
              return super.constructComponent(config);
              // my module extends with this new capability
           case `app-game-component`:
              return this.createGameComponent(config);
       }
}
```

But that doesn't work, my overrided `constructComponent` never appears to be called on my `GameContainer`. So that idea went out of the window.

**Will Angular Elements help me?**

My biggest problem at the moment is figuring out how to correctly deal with these 2 sets of `entryComponents`. I have ran out of options or strategy.

Then I read an article about `AngularElements` and what I am really wondering is if this may aid me here?  When I use `AngularElements` is it possible to register all my components at the App level so that my single `Container` has access to all "Factories" but yet still benefit from lazy loading?

Angular is saying "Look man, I don't know what `app-game` is" and this is causing me all kinds of nightmares since even when I load it, I now have some injector in some other place and I can't seem to deal with it.

Comment: I read that Decorators are not included by way of inheritance so later when my `Container` is a `Screen` it will contain Decorators and appears to become mirky

Comment: I think that is why Extension isn't really my preference. The fact that I have to duplicate my template and then remember to copy and paste Decorators... It isn't really viable just like all my other attempts aren't viable so far.  Hence Elements and there is no where I can find that describes exactly how they operate at runtime or with AOT. The documentation says it makes Dynamic Elements much easier to work with and that right now is killing me.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion is too long to put in a comment, and although it's not a very detailed answer (no code), it may be of use:

You could have a parent component, that has both the **dynamic components**, and the **lazy loaded module**

This can be achieved using *named router outlets* to load the lazy loaded modules from within the parent component. Here is an [example app](https://github.com/mchavaillaz/angular-router-named-outlet-lazy-loaded) of lazy loading with named outlets (you can run this on StackBlitz using the GitHub address)

**Note:** Lazy loading does not work by default in named router outlets, so you need to use the workaround in that app (see more details [Angular Issue #12842](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12842))

You could handle communication between the components using a shared service (keep in mind that services provided in lazy loaded modules, or provided in modules imported into lazy loaded modules, create new instances - see [shared modules and DI](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html) - also detailed in the Angular docs)

I would suggest building a demo app to test this this approach, rather than trying to edit your current app